# fb.ui apprequests giving me error code 2

Tags: jquery, facebook, api, sdk

So I have an app using the facebook javascript SDK(this is not a canvas app, it's standalone, just using the fb api to send some invites) I'm currently running it via localhost, it allows people to authorize the application and within a jQuery onclick handler it displays the following function to the logged in fb user.

```
function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
  FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        show_error: true,
        title: 'Title here',
        message: 'I\'ve sent you a message'
  }, function(result){
        alert(result);
  });
}
```

the FB.ui request works, the dialog appears I select an user and then I get the following error message:

```
API Error Code: 2
API Error Description: Service temporarily unavailable
Error Message: User can't send this request: Unknown error
```

I'm currently logged in as a test user that has befriended another test user, they have both authorized the application.

I'd be grateful for any advice on how to continue.

Answer (score 2):

There already is a bug report on this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/540196825997304

Please go there and add your repro so Facebook can better investigate the issue.

I will update this answer as soon as they answer the bug report.